# Mysql stranger syntax error #1064

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I've been searching for 20 minutes why I get this error in mySql but couldn't find an answer.

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5 "

Here is the code block in question:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE marouri_insert_users_emails()

BEGIN

DECLARE a INT;
DECLARE b char(16);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,name FROM glpi_users;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
 FETCH cur1 INTO a,b;

 IF a > 6 THEN
  INSERT INTO glpi_useremails(users_id,is_default,is_dynamic,email)  VALUES (a,1,0,CONCAT(b, '@alomrane.ma');
 END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

New to mysql btw. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple statements in a procedure or function or trigger, you must set another delimiter than `;`. Otherwise MySQL thinks, that your procedure is finished after the first `;`, which leads to the syntax error. Try it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE marouri_insert_users_emails()

BEGIN

DECLARE a INT;
DECLARE b char(16);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,name FROM glpi_users;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
 FETCH cur1 INTO a,b;

 IF a > 6 THEN
  INSERT INTO glpi_useremails(users_id,is_default,is_dynamic,email)  VALUES (a,1,0,CONCAT(b, '@alomrane.ma');
 END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Oh, and you might want to declare a continue handler to handle the situation when the cursor doesn't find more rows. Please see the [according manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html) for examples.

Comment: Have you added a continue handler? Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after variable and condition declarations. If this doesn't solve it, edit your question with the new code and the new error message.

Comment: Yes I added the continue handler. But then I realised I had missing parenthesis somewhere :)